# ACA Premium Tax Credit - Claiming for prior year

Tags: united-states, tax-credit, premiums, affordable-care-act

At the start of the year I did not think I would qualify for the subsidy, but as things have turned out my income was less than the maximum.

The health plan I used was available both through the government website and directly from the insurer.  Can I claim the ACA Premium Tax Credit on my 2016 return?  If so, what documents will I need?

Comment: When did your coverage start?

Comment: You claim the tax credit for the tax year in which it was received.  The government will send you a 1095-A  denoting your monthly premium as well as your monthly advance premium PTC.  You'll use form  8962 (Premium Tax Credit) in your filing and if your income ends up at your estimation, the tax credit is all yours.

Comment: @BobBaerker You should put that into an answer.

Comment: @AlexB, Sorry, I'm new here.  What's the difference if I put it as a comment or as an answer?

Comment: @BobBaerker No worries! :)  Welcome!   Comments are meant to be used to seek clarity and understand better what is being asked.   Answers are meant to be an answer to the question asked.   When you answer a question, the rest of the community can see that and vote yes/no on how well your answer tackles the question at hand.    Right now, this question has no answers so someone looking for the same problem might think there is no help for them here when your comment sounds like it is an answer.

Comment: Alex, Thanks for the clarification.  I posted it as an answer.  I'm taking over this topic !!!   ;->)

Answer (score 2):

You claim the tax credit for the tax year in which it was received. The government will send you a 1095-A denoting your monthly premium as well as your monthly advance premium PTC. You'll use form 8962 (Premium Tax Credit) in your filing and if your income ends up at your estimation, the tax credit is all yours.